# Solution for this error "InvalidArgument=Value of '0' is not valid for 'index'."

Tags: vb.net

The 'cause of error is when I trigger the event, I tried to disable it to prevent the error.
But, upon enabling it again. When, the event is triggered the error would show up again.

I Googled some solutions like checking if items exist in the ListView

```
If ListView2.Items.Count > 0 Then
```

I also, found some code on handling the event. But, It seems to do nothing.

```
AddHandler ListView2.SelectedIndexChanged, AddressOf ListView2_SelectedIndexChanged
```

I thought removing the items will remove the error. But, It didn't work.

Here is the code:

```
For i = ListView2.Items.Count - 1 To 0 Step -1
  ListView2.Items.Remove(ListView2.Items(i))
Next i
```

Below are the full codes for the event:

```
Private Sub ListView2_SelectedIndexChanged(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles ListView2.SelectedIndexChanged
    If ListView2.Items.Count > 0 Then
        TransactionID.Text = ListView2.SelectedItems(0).Text
        Label6.Left -= 190
        Label7.Left -= 190
        GroupBox1.Left -= 190
        ListView2.Left -= 190

        Button2.Visible = True
        ListView1.Visible = True
        GroupBox2.Visible = True
        Label4.Visible = True
        Label5.Visible = True
        ListView2.Enabled = False
        AddHandler ListView2.SelectedIndexChanged, AddressOf ListView2_SelectedIndexChanged
    End If
End Sub
```

I found out that the cause of the error is that I'm trying to select the ListView2 but, I no longer have access to it, there are no items in the Listview or I haven't selected it.
It's just strange the I made sure the Listview has items and the Listview is enabled.

So yeah... What could possibly the solution for this?

EDIT: ADDED THE CODE FOR BINDING THE LISTVIEW

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    If ComboBox1.Text = "" Then
        MsgBox("Please specify status of transaction!")
        ComboBox1.Focus()
    End If
    Dim conn As MySqlConnection
    conn = New MySqlConnection()
    Label6.Text = 0

    time = dateTo.Text
    format = "yyyy-MM-dd"
    outTo = (time.ToString(format))
    outTo = outTo & " " & "23:59:59"

    time = dateFrom.Text
    format = "yyyy-MM-dd"
    outFrom = (time.ToString(format))
    outFrom = outFrom & " " & "00:00:00"

    conn.ConnectionString = "server=localhost;user id=root;password=zhakige;database=singin"
    Dim strSQL = "SELECT transaction_id, transaction_status, transaction_staffusername ,transaction_date, transaction_totalprice FROM `transaction` WHERE transaction_date BETWEEN '" & outFrom & "' AND '" & outTo & "' AND transaction_status = '" & ComboBox1.Text & "';"
    conn.Open()
    Dim cmd = New MySqlCommand(strSQL, conn)
    Dim dr = cmd.ExecuteReader()
    ListView2.Items.Clear()

    Do While dr.Read()
        a = (dr.Item("transaction_id").ToString())
        b = (dr.Item("transaction_status").ToString())
        c = (dr.Item("transaction_staffusername").ToString())
        time = (dr.Item("transaction_date"))
        format = "yyyy-MM-dd"
        output = (time.ToString(format))
        d = output
        e2 = (dr.Item("transaction_totalprice").ToString())


        Dim lv As ListViewItem = ListView2.Items.Add(a)
        lv.SubItems.Add(b)
        lv.SubItems.Add(c)
        lv.SubItems.Add(d)
        lv.SubItems.Add(e2)
        Label6.Text += Val(e2)


    Loop
    If ListView2.Items.Count <= 0 Then
        MsgBox("No record found for specified options")
    End If

    dr.Close()
    cmd.Dispose()
    conn.Close()
End Sub
```

Comment: Please provide the code on how you bind the items to the ListView2.

Comment: @fapDaddy: Just edited it a minute ago.

Comment: What's the value of lv after this assignment?

    Dim lv As ListViewItem = ListView2.Items.Add(a)

Comment: The index where row it belongs.

Comment: The error persists even after you make the changes suggested by Steve?

You need to change 
"If ListView2.Items.Count > 0 Then" 
to 
"If ListView2.SelectedItems.Count > 0 Then".

Comment: Nope, I have accidentally added equals to the condition.
The problem when I click it the second time, the event is not continuous. It stops after the second time.

Answer (score 0):

[MSDN says](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listview.selecteditems.aspx)

> A ListView.SelectedListViewItemCollection that contains the items that
>   are selected in the control. If no items are currently selected, an
>   empty ListView.SelectedListViewItemCollection is returned.

So if you don't have any SelectedItems you can't use index 0 to read some value.
Change your code to

```
If ListView2.SelectedItems.Count > 0 Then
   ....
```

Answer (score 0):

Change this code

```
For i = ListView2.Items.Count - 1 To 0 Step -1
  ListView2.Items.Remove(ListView2.Items(i))
Next i
```

to

```
If ListView2.Items.Count > 0 Then
  For i = ListView2.Items.Count - 1 To 0 Step - 1
    ListView2.Items.Remove(ListView2.Items(i))
  Next i
End If
```

## Update

in this code

```
Private Sub ListView2_SelectedIndexChanged(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles ListView2.SelectedIndexChanged
  If ListView2.Items.Count > 0 Then
    TransactionID.Text = ListView2.SelectedItems(0).Text
    Label6.Left -= 190
    Label7.Left -= 190
    GroupBox1.Left -= 190
    ListView2.Left -= 190

    Button2.Visible = True
    ListView1.Visible = True
    GroupBox2.Visible = True
    Label4.Visible = True
    Label5.Visible = True
    ListView2.Enabled = False
    AddHandler ListView2.SelectedIndexChanged, AddressOf ListView2_SelectedIndexChanged
  End If
End Sub
```

the line that says

```
    ListView2.Enabled = False
```

disables the ListView2, so that should explain WHY and WHERE the ListView2 is being disabled

Also...
This line

```
AddHandler ListView2.SelectedIndexChanged, AddressOf ListView2_SelectedIndexChanged
```

attempts to assign an event handler to the same routine it is declared in!

```
Private Sub ListView2_SelectedIndexChanged(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles ListView2.SelectedIndexChanged
```

So chances are it probably does nothing new at all.